# Code Blocks and Sliders in WordPress Theme Development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

Hey I was just trying to build my own WordPress theme for my own site. But I wanted   it to look better so I wanted sliders and different Grid blocks in my theme like the other premium ones. But I can't find out how to code that. So I just wanted some sliders in the homepage and some latest post with different categories that I can manage it in different sections of homepage. So how can I code different dynamic blocks that can be used again and again in the homepage for different categories and post types so my theme would look like the professional ones along with the slider?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to code the slider, have a look at the wordpress plugin repository for sliders. LayerSlider, RevSlider, etc. There's a big amount of them and someones work with post type's.